# findAll() in Sequelize doesn't find a row created inside a transaction

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having a problem when creating a row and later on selecting it while still under the same transaction.

Whenever I execute the following code I usually get an empty array and rarely get an array with the newly created row.

This is a sample of the code I run:

```
return seq.transaction((tx) => {
    const options = {transaction: tx};
    return model.create(user, options)
    .then(() => {
        return model.findAll({
            include: {
                all: true
            }
    }, options)
    .then((data) => ({
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Is there something basic I'm missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem.
What I did wrong was giving the transaction to the findAll() function as an additional argument instead of part of the first argument's JSON.

So instead of:

```
return model.findAll({
    include: {
        all: true
    }
}, options)
```

I should've done:

```
return model.findAll({
    include: {
        all: true
    },
    transaction: options.transaction
});
```

Hope this solution will be helpful for other people.